# Aligning video behind image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to align a video behind an image so that it looks like you are changing channels on a tv set. Right now the video is small, and I can't adjust the size of the video. Any ideas or better ways of going about this?

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5" style="position:relative;">
   <div style="position:absolute;">
       <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oNBBijn4JuY?showinfo=0&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;margin:auto;position:relative;">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cqyrqtx4i7zwt0w/tvset_small_cropped.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e2syv64u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to play around with this, and got the video to be behind the image. I'm not sure how responsive this will be, but it looks like it will work.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5" style="position:relative;" id="tv">
    <div style="top:95px;left:37px;position:absolute;" id="player">
        <iframe width="415" height="333" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oNBBijn4JuY?showinfo=0&controls=0&wmode=opaque&origin=https://jsfiddle.net" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;margin:auto;position:relative;pointer-events: none;">
        <svg width="592" height="522" pointer-events="none" ="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <image x="0" y="0" width="592" height="522" xlink:href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cqyrqtx4i7zwt0w/tvset_small_cropped.png" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e2syv64u/12/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `left` and `top` properties just like you do in your fiddle, but you have to add `px` after the pixel number, e.g :

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:100px;">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I didn't do that in the fiddle, but I did update it in the question. I updated the fiddle to remove the top left styles. Still doesn't quite help, since the video is displaying small.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your page look like TV then create a 3x3 table and break your TV Box image into 8 pieces. Align these pieces together to recreate a TV and fill the center column with your Video. Go to following link for an example:

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/html_table_tutorial_rounded_corners.php3

With GrafiCode Studio's response you will not be able to press the play button.

Comment: Great suggestion. I will attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

your div renders correctly, but I can't see the video because there are cross origins problem (Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNBBijn4JuY?showinfo=0&wmode=opaque'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.):

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/e2syv64u/2/

```
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <header id="header"></header>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="main">
        <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5" style="position:relative;">
                <div style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:100px; background: #CCC;">
                    <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNBBijn4JuY?showinfo=0&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;margin:auto;position:relative;">
                    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cqyrqtx4i7zwt0w/tvset_small_cropped.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle to have https on the youtube video, I just forgot to hit the update button before posting the quesiton. The question has the correct https though.